# How do flights fly on some special days when there are firecrackers bursting near the source/destination airport?

Tags: takeoff, approach, descent

I mean there might be festive nights like New Year eve, when there is spectacular display of colorful firecrackers in the sky, but when there are flights descending or ascending near a city with an altitude of 3000 feet, I feel that it is risky enough to fly flights that low.

Comment: This may be a dupe of [this question](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/528/62) or [this one](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/53222/62)?

Answer (score 7):

Typical fireworks simply don't go that high. The *world record* for the highest firework ever is [3,700 feet](https://www.quora.com/What-altitude-do-commercial-fireworks-typically-reach). Most fireworks only reach [200-500 feet](https://keystonefireworks.com/news/how-high-do-fireworks-shoot/) before exploding. The very biggest commercially available fireworks may be able to reach [1,000 feet](https://www.skylighter.com/blogs/fireworks-information/firework-display-charts).

Firework displays are basically treated like cranes or any other obstacle that might be erected in the vicinity of an airport. A NOTAM will be issued, and pilots will know not to fly near the display. Not to mention that they're pretty easy to see, given how bright the typical firework is. But it rarely matters, since the only time a typical plane will be flying that low is if it's just about to land or had just taken off.

Comment: Good answer.  I might just add that displays aren't generally planned in the immediate vicinity of airports, and at night they are super easy to see and avoid.

Comment: @MichaelHall Good point, I think I'll add it to the answer.

Comment: Not too long after I got my PPL, I thought it'd be cool to watch a 4th of July fireworks show from the air. We were somewhere around 1500-2000 AGL and maybe 3 nautical miles away (outside the NOTAM'd area). We were tremendously disappointed. Even from that relatively low height (and we didn't want to go lower at night) the fireworks were _tiny_ little things, way _way_ below us. They just looked like tiny little sparks. The gas money could've been much better spent!

Comment: @MichaelHall My home airport hosts a fireworks show every year. It used to be directly adjacent to the field (under downwind leg), but now they close the airport and launch everything from the runway itself :-(